# Opening PDF document in adobe acrobat instead reader

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, pdf

We have PDF documents in SharePoint 2013 document library. We have installed both Adobe Acrobat and Reader on our machine. When we open PDF document, it opens up in Reader by default. But we want the document should be opened in Adobe acrobat instead by default. How we can switch this default behavior. we don't want to uninstall Adobe reader due to some reasons. any useful suggestion ?

Comment: As per my understanding, browser simply call the default application of the system. Set Adobe Acrobat as default PDF application of the system and it should work.

Comment: @Mohit, you should copy your comment as answer, since this is really the solution for the issue as far as I see

Comment: OK. But how i set Adobe Acrobat as Default PDF application ? How i set this in IE 10 ?

Comment: Ok, I have found and i have set Adobe Acrobat as Default PDF in browser. in IE, i do like this: Internet Options-> Programs-> Set Programs-> Set Default Programs -> The i click Adobe Acrobat and click on "Set this program as default" at the below. But still when i opened PDF document   from Document library, it still opens in Reader? Whts wrong?

Comment: @pholpar thanks for suggestion.Please mark as answer to help others

Answer (score 3):

As per my understanding, browser simply call the default application of the system. Set Adobe Acrobat as default PDF application of the system and it should work.